# Python string expression evaluation with variable

Tags: string, python-3.x, logic

I have an expression string "2 + (y * 11) = 42"
and i intend to isolate "y" to the LHS and 
transform the string into "y = (42 - 2) / 11"

How can I do so, I'm new to python3.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at [`sypmy`](https://www.sympy.org/).

Comment: the problem is only to transform the string by isolating the variable on one side, not to solve it. I'm not sure if it is possible to isolate the variable using sympy or z3.

Comment: ...isolating the variable (in your case) is the same as solving the equation. i'm not sure you can do that with less code if you do not want to use `sympy`.

Comment: all I need to do is keep the equation intact while isolating the variable

Comment: in general? or just for a linear equation? i'd still guess sympy is the simplest way to go.

Comment: just a linear equation with operations restricted to +, -, *, /

Comment: i did manage to solve the equation to get the variable's value by using z3 (similar to sympy) but that is not the objective, all I need to do is perform the string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `sympy` installed, you can do this:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
y = Symbol('y')
sol = solve(2 + (y * 11) - 42, y)
print(sol)  # [40/11]
```

note that `solve` will try to find a root of the polynomial on the LHS - therefore the `- 42`.

Comment: the problem is only to transform the string by isolating the variable on one side, not to solve it. I'm not sure if it is possible to isolate the variable using sympy or z3